# Non Responsive GUI for java server

Tags: java, user-interface, server

I am trying to create a GUI for a small project. This project is a java server, at the moment my code works fine, the server is connected and all but it never gets out of a loop and therefore the Frame of the GUI is created and displayed but you cannot interact with it after wards. I know where is the loop, but I cant seem to find a way to make my server listen to new clients and still be able to interact with the GUI. Here is my Code:

```
public class MainServerFrame {

    private static JFrame frame;
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    private static Socket clientSocket = null;
    private static final int maxClientsCount = 999;
    private static final clientThread[] threads = new clientThread[maxClientsCount];
    private static StudentStoring studentDB = new StudentStoring();

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainServer();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void MainServer() {

        // The default port number.
        int portNumber = 3333;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("SERVER ONLINE");
        initialize();
        MainServerFrame window = new MainServerFrame();
        MainServerFrame.getFrame().setVisible(true);
        /*
         * Create a client socket for each connection and pass it to a new client
         * thread.
         */
```

HERE IS WHERE I CREATE THE SOCKET AND THEN GET INTO THE LOOP, what kind of design could I use to get rid of this while loop ?

```
        while (true) {
            try {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                int i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
                    if (threads[i] == null) {
                        (threads[i] = new clientThread(clientSocket, threads, studentDB)).start();
                        System.out.println("client " + i + " is connected");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (i == maxClientsCount) {
                    PrintStream os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                    os.println("Server too busy. Try later.");
                    os.close();
                    clientSocket.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private static void initialize() {
        setFrame(new JFrame());
        getFrame().setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        getFrame().setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel lblServer = new JLabel("SERVER:");
        getFrame().getContentPane().add(lblServer, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    }

    public static JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }

    public static void setFrame(JFrame frame) {
        MainServerFrame.frame = frame;
    }

}
```

**MY CLIENT**

```
import java.awt.Font;

public class MainFrame implements Runnable {
    //declare Jpanel
    private static JFrame frmHome;
    // The client socket
    private static Socket clientSocket = null;
    // The output stream
    static ObjectOutputStream os;
    // The input stream
    static ObjectInputStream is;
    private static BufferedReader inputLine = null;
    private static boolean closed = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        // The default port.
        int portNumber = 3333;
        // The default host.
        String host = "localhost";
        /*
         * Open a socket on a given host and port. Open input and output streams.
         */
        try {
          clientSocket = new Socket(host, portNumber);
          is = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
          os = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
          os.flush();
          System.out
          .println("CONNECTED TO SERVER\n"
              + "Now using host=" + host + ", portNumber=" + portNumber);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
          System.err.println("Don't know about host " + host);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to the host "
              + host);
        }

        /*
         * If everything has been initialized then we want to write some data to the
         * socket we have opened a connection to on the port portNumber.
         */
        if (clientSocket != null && os != null && is != null) {
          /* Create a thread to read from the server. */
          new Thread(new MainFrame()).start();
        }
      }

      public void run() {
        /*
         * Keep on reading from the socket till we receive "Bye" from the
         * server. Once we received that then we want to break.
         */
          MainFrame window = new MainFrame();
          MainFrame.frmHome.setVisible(true);
        String responseLine;
        try {
          while (!closed) {

          }
        } finally{
            try {
                is.close();
                os.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }

    public MainFrame() {
        initialize();
    }

    //function to make window visible
    void setVisible() throws IOException {
        main(null);
    }

    private void initialize() {
        //Initialise Main window with 3 options.
        frmHome = new JFrame();
        frmHome.setTitle("Home");
        frmHome.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 372);
        frmHome.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmHome.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frmHome.setResizable(false);

        JLabel lblWelcomeToSrs = new JLabel("Welcome to SRS");
        lblWelcomeToSrs.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        lblWelcomeToSrs.setBounds(86, 183, 112, 14);
        frmHome.getContentPane().add(lblWelcomeToSrs);

        //initialise all buttons and labels of window.
        JButton btnAdStu = new JButton("Add a student");
        btnAdStu.setBounds(10, 207, 126, 23);
        btnAdStu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                AddStudentFrame adus;
                try {
                    try {
                        adus = new AddStudentFrame();
                        adus.setVisible();
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    frmHome.setVisible(false);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        frmHome.getContentPane().add(btnAdStu);

        JButton btnCheckStud = new JButton("Search / Modify");
        btnCheckStud.setBounds(146, 207, 127, 23);
        btnCheckStud.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                SearchFrame searchFrame;
                searchFrame = new SearchFrame();
                searchFrame.setVisible();
            }
        });
        frmHome.getContentPane().add(btnCheckStud);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        frmHome.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblCreatedByRmi = new JLabel("Created by R\u00E9mi Tuyaerts");
        lblCreatedByRmi.setBounds(147, 318, 184, 14);
        frmHome.getContentPane().add(lblCreatedByRmi);  

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Complete List of Students");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                CompleteListFrame studentList = new CompleteListFrame();
                studentList.setVisible();
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(52, 241, 184, 23);
        frmHome.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        // wonderful pictures of his excellence design by Yasser
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("");
        Image img = new ImageIcon(frmHome.getClass().getResource("/michaelchung.jpg")).getImage();
        lblNewLabel_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(80, 11, 120, 148);
        frmHome.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing I'd like to mention is the use of `static` in your method signatures. They should *not* be `static` , and you should *not* be trying to access them statically (`MainServerFrame.getFrame().setVisible(true);`). Take out the `static` in all the method signatures, add access the methods like `window.getFrame().setVisible(true);`

Secondly, the `MainServerFrame` is being created on the Event Dispatch Thread. The EDT handle all the UI interaction. Though your code is not complete, it appears the `while` loop is in the `MainServerFrame`'s constructor. The problem with this is that the `while` loops blocks the event thread, causing the unresponsiveness. To fix it, you could simply start a new thread for the while loop.

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            ...
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Any calls inside this new thread, which attempts to update the UI, should be wrapped in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`. Something like

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            ...
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    label.setText(...);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}).start();
```

- Check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

---

Here's a simple refactor. I took out some of the code just to make the example simpler

```
public class MainServerFrame {

    private JFrame frame;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    private Socket clientSocket = null;
    private int maxClientsCount = 999;
    private JTextArea serverLog = new JTextArea(10, 40);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainServerFrame app = new MainServerFrame();
                    app.getFrame().setVisible(true);
                    app.startServer();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public MainServerFrame() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(serverLog);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    }

    public JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }

    public void startServer() {
         int portNumber = 3333;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                        final String data = 
                                (new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream())).readUTF();
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                            public void run() {
                                serverLog.append(data);
                                serverLog.append("\n");
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Simple client

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cilent {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 3333);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String data = scanner.nextLine();
        (new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())).writeUTF(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but if they are not static how can i access it from the main ?

Comment: I thought I explained that. Access the instance `window`

Comment: If you need to make everything static, then there is a problem with your design. Do some research on the difference between instance and static. static is more than just being able to access something from the main. There are reasons to make things static. And just being able to access something from the main, is not a good enough reason to make everything static. Take some time to rethink the design

Comment: I did what you've explained tahnks, but I have a problem with running MainServer() in my main(). I tried to create the variable window outside the functions to make it accessible to all of them but it still tells me i should make it static I'm really confused

Comment: Have a look at my update. I did a little refactoring. You can get some ideas from it. I never once use `static`

Comment: OK thanks you so much so now i just need to add my tread while loop in the Thread (runnable) ?

Comment: It seems like that's all you would need to do to make the UI responsive. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: Basically you are just doing all the server stuff in a separate thread. When you call `startServer` (or in your case `MainServer`), it is being called inside the `EventQueue.invokeLater` which is inside the Event Dispatch Thread. All I'm going above is putting the `while` loop inside a different thread, so it no longer blocks the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: I've just tried and it does not seem to work. The gui of the server comes up, and no error is printed, i can run a client no probs, but the GUI of the client doesnt come up. And nothing is printed in the log.

Comment: Hard to tell what you're doing wrong. I have to simplify my code, as your post was missing many things. Please run my server code, and I post a simple client program. Start the Server them start the client. Type something into the client (console) and you will see it get printed to server log

Comment: Besides, you are talking about a problem with the client, in which your post shows no client code

Comment: Also remember, since we are working in a different tread from the EDT, all update to the UI, should be made inside a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`

Comment: ok i will give it a go, I have updated my client to my first post